# boost::atomic with boost::optional different behavior with boost 1.55 and 1.58

Tags: c++, boost, atomic

```
struct Foo
{
   void updateMin(const int& value);

   boost::atomic<boost::optional<int>> m_min; //multi-thread access
};

void Foo::updateMin(const int& value)
{
    auto currentMin = m_min.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed);
    int newMin;

    do
    {
        if (!currentMin)
            newMin = value;
        else
        {
            newMin = std::min(value, currentMin.get());
            if (newMin == currentMin)
                break;
        }

    } while (!m_min.compare_exchange_weak(currentMin, boost::optional<int>(newMin), boost::memory_order_relaxed));
}
```

With boost 1.55 the above code work as expected.

When I tried to update boost version to 1.58, the compare_exchange_weak fail systematically and so lead to an infinite loop.

I have ridden the change logs of both atomic and optional since 1.55 but I found nothing really obvious to explain this behavior.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like `std::atomic`, [`boost::atomic` requires trivially copyable types](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/atomic/interface.html#atomic.interface.interface_atomic_object).
`boost::optional` is not trivially copyable, so you just get undefined behavior.

By the way, `compare_exchange_*` compares the objects as if by `memcmp`, so it would take into account any padding bytes as well.